# Py2app throwing import error image not found with pyside

Tags: py2app

I'm trying to build an app using PySide with py2app but I'm having problems actually running the app.

I've tried a number of variations on the setup.py file for importing PySide but nothing works. I've placed in setup_requires, install_requires, OPTIONS, a direct import at the top of the setup.py file to this point.

Here is what my current setup.py file looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup
import PySide

APP = ['login.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'includes': 'PySide'}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Here is what it looks like when I build the setup.py file

```
$ python setup.py py2app -A
running py2app
creating /Users/x/Desktop/Pycharm/desktop-app/build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app
creating /Users/x/Desktop/Pycharm/desktop-app/build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/x/Desktop/Pycharm/desktop-app/build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/temp
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/Frameworks
```

But when I try to run my app it hangs and crashes with the following traceback

```
Jul 13 10:53:23  login[93037] <Notice>: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jul 13 10:53:23  login[93037] <Notice>:   File "/Users/x/Desktop/Pycharm/desktop-app/dist/login.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 376, in <module>
Jul 13 10:53:23  login[93037] <Notice>:     _run()
Jul 13 10:53:23  login[93037] <Notice>:   File "/Users/x/Desktop/Pycharm/desktop-app/dist/login.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 370, in _run
Jul 13 10:53:23  login[93037] <Notice>:     exec(compile(source, script, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
Jul 13 10:53:23  login[93037] <Notice>:   File "/Users/x/Desktop/Pycharm/desktop-app/login.py", line 10, in <module>
Jul 13 10:53:23  login[93037] <Notice>:     from utils import capture_image, manage_media, base_image_extraction, vehicle, django_communication
Jul 13 10:53:23  login[93037] <Notice>:   File "/Users/x/Desktop/Pycharm/desktop-app/utils/capture_image.py", line 11, in <module>
Jul 13 10:53:23  login[93037] <Notice>:     from PySide.QtGui import (QPixmap, QImage)
Jul 13 10:53:23  login[93037] <Notice>: ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib
Jul 13 10:53:23  login[93037] <Notice>:   Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so
Jul 13 10:53:23  login[93037] <Notice>:   Reason: image not found
Jul 13 10:53:23  login[93037] <Notice>: 2016-07-13 10:53:23.898 login[93037:362066] login Error
```

I checked the path and the mentioned files all exist so I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anyone encounters the issue it is because you have to brew install pyside. pip install pyside will cause this issue but I have no idea why.